# Google Maps React Markers and List

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I was wondering if anyone has used google-maps-react library to create Markers and List Items. I have a map component that is rendering the Map, Markers and Info Window. I also have another component that has all List (li) of places that represent each Marker's value. Is there someway that I can click on the list item, and trigger the appropriate Marker's click event.

Answer (score 0):

If List is holding the information of your Markers, you need to uplift state as you are trying to communicate from Child to Parent. So ideally, Markers positions live in the parent, as well as  the function to call (Map in your case). And you call it from your list item passing the function via props to the List component like so:

```
<List handleMarkers={this.function}/>
```

Access the function in the child via this.props.handleMarkers.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you mean [`google-maps-react` library](https://github.com/fullstackreact/google-maps-react), right? 
Lets say you have a component to select an address:

```
const CityList = props => {
  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        {props.items.map((item, index) => {
          return (
            <li key={index} onClick={e => props.onClick(e, item)}>
              {item.title}
            </li>
          );
        })}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Then you could introduce a *selected value* as state and update the state once the address list item is clicked. Updating the state will trigger a rerender of the `Map` component:

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    selectedItem: { lat: 0, lng: 0 }
  };

  showInfo(e, selectedItem) {
    this.setState({ selectedItem: selectedItem });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <CityList items={data} onClick={this.showInfo.bind(this)} />
        <MapContainer
          center={{ lat: -24.9923319, lng: 135.2252427 }}
          zoom={4}
          data={data}
          selectedItem={this.state.selectedItem}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

[Here is a **demo**](https://codesandbox.io/s/x9mqr94m8z) for your reference